# file_get_contents(url) failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, html, mysql, curl

I am starting to get this error today when I try to open the link.
I tried `curl` version but still getting same error. This error happened when I added `cloudfare` to my website. Does it have an effect?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  include'config.php';
  $items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phil");
  $thispage = $PHP_SELF;
  $num = mysql_num_rows($items);
  $per_page = 500;
  $start = @$_GET['start'];
  if(empty($start)) $start = 0;
    ?>
      <center>
        <?php
          if($start+$per_page<$num){
            ?>
              [<a href="<?php print("$thispage?start=".max(0,$start+$per_page)); ?>">Next Like</a>]
            <?php
          }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phil ORDER BY id LIMIT $start,$per_page");
    if($result){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $token = $row[access_token];
        $userData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token.'&fields=name,id'),true);print($userData[name]).'<br/>';
       if(!$userData[name]){
         mysql_query("
                    DELETE FROM
                    phil
                    WHERE
                    access_token='" . mysql_real_escape_string($token) . "'
                  ");
       }
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: `$row['access_token']` you missed the quotes. Same for `$userdata`. Also. It helps to put the URL in a variable first and echo it. Just to see how it actually looks like.

Comment: Does `var_dump($row['access_token']);` output what you expect?